# Change a child Component using a JPanel reference?

Tags: java, swing, components, jpanel

I have a `JPanel panel` with a bill designed and populated inside it.

I passed it to a printer function - which used `iText` to save it to a pdf.
The basic flow of code is like this.

```
void printToPdf(JPanel panel)   {
    ...
    Image toEmbed = generateImage(panel);
    doc.add(toEmbed)
    ...
}
```

Now, according to the new requirements, i need to make four copies of the bill (within the same pdf document). Each copy has a different value for a `copyName JTextField` (Seller, Buyer, etc).

Is there a way i can change the value of `copyName` within `prinToPdf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the JTextField, just call setText() on it in each iteration, at the end just restore the first one.

Comment: ha, that makes sense. Trying it now 8|